# Statistical test for rubric-scored student responses

Tags: statistical-significance, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am generally a qualitative researcher, but in my current study I am asking a research question that requires (very little, but some) quantitative tools. Simplistically, I have scored students' responses to a mathematics question using a rubric which is scaled from 1-5. First, I scored their response as they wrote it on their task sheet. Then, I scored their responses as they verbalized it. I want to consider whether there is a statistically significant difference in the verbal/written modality of their responses. The sample size is 26. Should I use a Wilcoxon-signed rank test? What is the appropriate test for this?

Comment: As it stands the question is not sufficiently clear to identify a good answer. Can you say more about the scoring of the response? You will also need to more carefully identify your null and alternative hypothesis (which is not a statement about samples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Wilcoxon signed-rank test may be OK.  Here is an example with $n = 26$ pairs of (fake) scores I generated for purposes of illustration:  $X_i$ for Math, $Y_i$ for Verbal, and $D_i = Y_i - X_i$ for the difference.

Here is a table from R statistical software of these data, where the numbers in brackets (column labels) show
student numbers:

```
 rbind(x, y, d)
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
x    2    2    3    3    4    4    2    4    4     3
y    2    1    3    4    4    5    2    5    5     4
d    0   -1    0    1    0    1    0    1    1     1
  [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19]
x     2     2     4     4     2     3     4     2     3
y     3     3     5     4     2     4     4     2     3
d     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
  [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26]
x     3     3     3     1     4     4     4
y     3     2     2     2     5     5     5
d     0    -1    -1     1     1     1     1
```

We can get a quick overview of the results by looking at a tally of the differences in scores. In this example all of the differences happened to be -1 (better on math: 3 students), 0 (same on both: 10 students), +! (better on verbal: 13 students):

```
table(d) 
d
-1  0  1 
 3 10 13
```

**Wilcoxon signed-rankd test.** In R, you can do the Wilcoxon signed-rank test, on the $(X_i, Y_i)$ pairs as follows:

```
    Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity
    correction

data:  x and y
V = 25.5, p-value = 0.01349
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning messages:
1: In wilcox.test.default(x, y, pair = T) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(x, y, pair = T) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

Equivalently, you can do a one-sample test on the differences, obtaining the same P-value (and warning messages):

```
wilcox.test(d)$p.val 
[1] 0.0134891
```

The P-value $0.01349 < 0.5$ indicates that you can reject the null $H_0: \mu_D = 0$ that there is no significant difference between math and verbal scores, at the 5% level of significance (against the alternative $H_a: \mu_D \ne 0.)$

However, there are two warning messages. As originally conceived, such nonparametric tests are based on the assumption that that the differences are from a continuous distribution. In particular, these tests are based on ranks, and ranking becomes more complicated when there are ties. Modern implementations of the Wilcoxon signed-rank test use approximations to
mitigate the difficulties caused by ties, but the warning message lets you know that the P-value may not be exactly correct. Also, when there are $0$'s 
among the differences, additional difficulties interpreting ties may arise.

**Alternative tests.** One alternative way to look at our (fake) data is to do a ***sign test.***
We can ignore the 10 students with $0$-difference scores because they offer no evidence of a difference. Out of the remaining $16$ students there are $3$ negative scores and $13$ positive ones.

If there is no
difference between math and verbal scores, there should be nearly a 50:50 split. The binomial distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(15, 1/2)$ the probability of a spit as far or farther from 8:8 than we have observed is only 0.0213, and we can take this as the P-value of a sign test, rejecting the null hypothesis at the 5% level.

```
2*pbinom(3, 16, .5)
[1] 0.02127075
```

Another possibility starts by doing a paired ***t-test*** on the $D_i.$

```
t.test(d)

        One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = 2.8127, df = 25, p-value = 0.009424
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1029911 0.6662397
sample estimates:
mean of x 
0.3846154
```

With its P-value $\approx 0.01 < .05,$ the t test also rejects $H_0.$ The
t test is legendary for its robustness against certain kinds of non-normality.
However, you may feel our highly-discrete $D_i$'s is stretching the reliance
on robustness too far.

There is nothing wrong with the $T$-statistic as
as a measure of the distance of $\bar D$ from $0,$ but it is hard to claim
that the $T$ statistic has exactly Student's t distribution with $\nu = 25$ degrees of freedom. Thus we must admit that the P-value from this t test may not be exactly correct.

***Permutation test.*** If $H_0$ is true, then it ought to make no difference if we randomly scrambled the $\pm$-signs of the $D_i.$ By randomly scrambling the signs
and getting a $T$ statistic for each scrambled version of the $D_i$'s we can
get a good approximation of the true distribution of the $T$-statistic under
$H_0.$ This is called the *simulated permutation distribution* of $T,$ which can be found as below. The last step shows the probability of a more extreme
value than we obtained using the original $D_i$'s just above. The P-value of the permutation test is $0.021 < 0.025,$ so we reject $H_0.$

```
set.seed(1234)
t = replicate( 10^6, t.test( sample(c(-1,1), 26, rep=T)*d)$stat)
mean(abs(t) >= 2.8127)
[1] 0.021408
```

The figure below shows the simulated permutation distribution of $T.$
It is obviously not distributed exactly according to Student's t distribution, but it's tail probabilities are useful.The P-value is the probability outside the vertical broken lines (at $\pm 2.8127).$

[image]

For data with only values $-1, 0,$ and $1,$ it might be argued that the
permutation test is not much different than a sign test. But in most
practical applications I suppose you would have a wider variety of score
differences than in my fake data.

In summary, the Wilcoxon signed-rank test may well work for your data.
But if you have doubts about its validity, you know now that there are other tests you can use.